# put Custom Class Array into a dataset or XML (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, dataset

I am making a small card game which requires a high score list that is saved to an external file, and loaded from it at the beginning of each each game.

I wrote an XML file in this format:

```
<highscore>
<name>bob</name>
<score>10</score>
<time>3:42</time>
<date>21-09-09</date>
</highscore>
```

I have figured out how to create a dataset, use `dataset.readxml`, to load the XML into it, create a row and then write each row into an array of HighScores:

```
class HighScore
{
string nameString, timeString, dateString;
int scoreInt;
}
```

I have also figured out how to check if the games highscore is higher than the lowest in the array.

I'm working on the sort, but how can I get the `HighScore[]` array back into a dataset then into the XML, or even from the array straight to the dataset? I have tried to Google it, but I haven't found what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use a `DataSet` just to serialize your array? If you only need to serialize an array you can use simple Xml Serialization. Here's an example:

```
    [XmlRoot("highScore")]
    public class HighScore
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("dateTime")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("score")]
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IList<HighScore> highScores = new[] { 
            new HighScore {Name = "bob", Date = DateTime.Now, Score = 10 },
            new HighScore {Name = "john", Date = DateTime.Now, Score = 9 },
            new HighScore {Name = "maria", Date = DateTime.Now, Score = 28 }
        };


        // serializing Array
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HighScore[]));
        using (Stream st = new FileStream(@"c:\test.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            s.Serialize(st, highScores.ToArray());
        }

        // deserializing Array
        HighScore[] highScoresArray;
        using (Stream st = new FileStream(@"c:\test.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            highScoresArray = (HighScore[])s.Deserialize(st);
        }

        foreach (var highScore in highScoresArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2} ", highScore.Name, highScore.Date, highScore.Score);
        }
    }
```